# What are the benefits of DefaultSelenium over SeleneseTestCase class?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I want to know what are the benefits of `DefaultSelenium` over `SeleneseTestCase` class??

What `DefaultSelenium` is good in ?

What `SeleneseTestCase` is good in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: Selenium RC has been deprecated over a year ago. There will be no more development. Use Selenium WebDriver whenever you can, it brings so much goodness with it!

Second: `SeleneseTestCase` has been *doubly* deprecated, because it's a helper class for JUnit 3, but JUnit 4 has been with us since 2006. Use JUnit 4 whenever you can, it brings so much goodness with it!

Anyway,

[`DefaultSelenium`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html) controls the browser. It is a direct mirror of what `FirefoxDriver` and `InternetExplorerDriver` (and others) are to Selenium WebDriver. It is the basic class you should be interacting with (via the [`Selenium`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html) interface which is the same as the [`WebDriver`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) interface from WebDriver). It's the brain behind Selenium RC and allows you to use all the Selenium RC methods like this:

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://google.com");
selenium.start();
selenium.doWhateverYouWantToDoNow();
```

[`SeleneseTestCase`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/SeleneseTestCase.html), on the other hand, is nothing like it. You could (but shouldn't, remember?) `extend` it to bring its goodness to you. It contains multiple JUnit 3 convenience methods suitable for use with Selenium, most notably [`setUp()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/SeleneseTestCase.html#setUp%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`tearDown()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/SeleneseTestCase.html#tearDown%28%29) which internally start (stop) an instance of `DefaultSelenium`. It's a convenience class you could extend and that could save you some typing, but it still uses `DefaultSelenium`.